# in post content shortcode works, but hardcoded in same page template doesn't?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

So I have a super simple Woocommerce shortcode [product_categories], It's supposed to show product categories from the shop.

It does this job perfectly if I put it inside the contents of a page as such: [product_categories].

However, if I put the same thing into the template directly it suddenly returns the first post of current category? What?!

So in my template I have only these two rows:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product categories]'); // this returns a single product which is wrong and totally weird ?>
<?php the_content(); // this returns the categories as intended ?>
```

I never knew these two methods have some kind of difference. How can I make the shortcode work with the echo way?

Comment: You are missing the "_" in your shortcode. It should be `[product_category]` or  `[product_categories]`. Please check if this is the problem here. Example from the official [WooCommerce shortcode documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/): `[product_categories number="0" parent="0"]`

Comment: @LWS-Mo If `[product_categories]` is working, it should work here as well, the other stuff are filter / limit  parameters. but good point here : "_"  
jussi if you've copied the code directly from the template file, please recheck if that's the case as you've mentioned that it works but shows only one product.

Comment: Yes `[product_categories]` is working. But if the shortcode `[product categories]` is used, this will show a single product. Because `[product]` is just a shortcode to show products. To show the product categories itself `[product_categories]` should be used. It seems that @Jussi has just forgot the underscore in his shortcode.

Comment: Omg... feeling stupid after the answer is so humiliatingly easy is never getting old for me. Yes, the problem was the lack of underscore for christs sake. To think I have the balls to consider myself a WP developer.

Comment: it was like missing a `;` while coding, i recommend you should always copy the shortcode from the available shortcode list to avoid these minor mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lacking the underscore in [product categories].

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_categories]'); ?>
```

Above code with "_" returns the correct answer.